# How to set the selecteditem

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying to set the value/selecteditem of a listpicker control - from the silverlight toolkit for windows phone 7 (when the user wants to edit an entry in xml, it pulls the data out of IO and sets it in the text boxes/listpickers).

I am currently trying to use:

```
ListPickerSub.SelectedItem = sub;
```

(sub is a string)

But it is throwing a System.InvalidOperationException

```
Additional information: SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value.
```

Comment: What is `sub`? Does it actually belong to the list?

Comment: it is a value of one of the elements in storage yes, say i was using xElement("subElement").Value to set the data binding. sub is a identical value to the value in subElement. I have also tried (just to test) by setting the listpicker's content statically:

<sys:String>monday</sys:String>
<sys:String>sunday</sys:String>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedItem` is expecting a ListPickerItem (which is one of the items in the list). You're passing it a string - hence the error.

You may find it easier to set the `SelectedIndex`.

It's hard to give a relevant example of setting the SelectedItem without knowing what you're populating the list with.

**Edit:**
Here's an example of how you could bind to strings. Without a workable example of what you are actually binding to the itemsource this is hte best I can do. (Just giving the name of the object or partial code isn't enough.)

Assuming:

```
<Controls:ListPicker x:Name="ListPickerSub">
    <Controls:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <Controls:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</Controls:ListPicker>
```

Then I can bind the contents with:

```
ListPickerSub.ItemsSource = SubItems();


private IEnumerable<string> SubItems()
{
    yield return "monday";
    yield return "tuesday";
    yield return "wednesday";
    yield return "thursday";
    yield return "friday";
    yield return "saturday";
    yield return "sunday";
}
```

and set the `SelectedItem` with:

```
ListPickerSub.SelectedItem = "sunday";
```

Comment: I am populating the list like this:

    `<toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="{Binding subName}" Text="{Binding subName}" Margin="0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>`

Comment: @Jamie but what are you passing as the ItemSource?

Comment: Binding subName.

I did try using: object index = SubTxt.FindName(sub); then setting the selecteditem as index but index always returned as null

Comment: Thank you so much, that is working perfectly. 

Only problem i am having is in my settings where i set the listpicker like so:
`<sys:string>monday</sys:string>`
for each value and as with all of my settings, i have used a two way binding to set the selecteditem:

`SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppSettings}, Path=WeekBeginsSetting, Mode=TwoWay}`

This binding returns the correct value because I have used it to set the text of a textblock (just to test). But when trying to set the selecteditem it throws a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: @Jamie please ask this new question as a new question. If you can post a complete example which demonstrates the problem this will help you get a faster, more relevant answer.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following:

```
ListPickerSub.SelectedItem = ListPickerSub.Items.First(x => (x as ListPickerItem).Content.ToString() == sub);
```

You may need to cast the Content to TextBlock, and change the code accordingly.  The above works for my case where ListPicker is populated dynamically using ListPickerItem.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want to set the data in the underlying datasource and then just refresh your list?